# I need to merge two files and create a new files

Tags: shell, awk

input 1

**1 10611** 2   122 **C**:0.983607  **G**:0.0163934

input 2

**1 10611** rs146752890 **C**   **G**   100 PASS    AC=184;RSQ=0.8228;AVGPOST=0.9640;AN=2184;ERATE=0.0031;VT=SNP;AA=.;THETA=0.0127;LDAF=0.0902;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AF=0.08;ASN_AF=0.08;AMR_AF=0.14;AFR_AF=0.08;EUR_AF=0.07

here 
1st and 2nd column are matching and values before ':' of 5th column of first file and 4th column of 2nd files are equel and 6th column(values before ':') of first and 5th column of second  files are equel and output is creating based on this match.Will get the clear idea from input and output line and both files are .gz files

output

1   10611   rs146752890 C   G   100 PASS AC=184;RSQ=0.8228;AVGPOST=0.9640;AN=2184;ERATE=0.0031;VT=SNP;AA=.;THETA=0.0127;LDAF=0.0902;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AF=0.08;ASN_AF=0.08;AMR_AF=0.14;AFR_AF=0.08;EUR_AF=0.07;**REF=0.983607;ALT=0.0163934;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { split($5,a,":"); split($6,b,":"); c[$1,$2,a[1],b[1]]="REF=" a[2] ";ALT=" b[2] ";"; next } ($1,$2,$4,$5) in c { print $0 ";" c[$1,$2,$4,$5] }' input1 input2
```

Result:

```
1 10611 rs146752890 C G 100 PASS AC=184;RSQ=0.8228;AVGPOST=0.9640;AN=2184;ERATE=0.0031;VT=SNP;AA=.;THETA=0.0127;LDAF=0.0902;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AF=0.08;ASN_AF=0.08;AMR_AF=0.14;AFR_AF=0.08;EUR_AF=0.07;REF=0.983607;ALT=0.0163934;
```

So for compressed files, try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { split($5,a,":"); split($6,b,":"); c[$1,$2,a[1],b[1]]="REF=" a[2] ";ALT=" b[2] ";"; next } ($1,$2,$4,$5) in c { print $0 ";" c[$1,$2,$4,$5] }' <(gzip -dc input1.gz) <(gzip -dc input2.gz) | gzip > output.gz
```

*EDIT:*

From the comments below, try this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { split($5,a,":"); split($6,b,":"); c[$1,$2,a[1],b[1]]="REF=" a[2] ";ALT=" b[2] ";"; next } ($1,$2,$4,$5) in c { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, c[$1,$2,$4,$5] $8 ";" }' file1 file2
```

Result:

```
1 10611 rs146752890 C G 100 PASS REF=0.983607;ALT=0.0163934;AC=184;RSQ=0.8228;AVGPOST=0.9640;AN=2184;ERATE=0.0031;VT=SNP;AA=.;THETA=0.0127;LDAF=0.0902;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AF=0.08;ASN_AF=0.08;AMR_AF=0.14;AFR_AF=0.08;EUR_AF=0.07;
```

Comment: Can u add REF=0.983607;ALT=0.0163934; fields at the starting of 8th column.Like **1 10611 rs146752890 C G 100 PASS REF=0.983607;ALT=0.0163934;AC=184;RSQ=0.8228;AVGPOST=0.9640;AN=2184;ERATE=0.0031;VT=SNP;AA=.;THETA=0.0127;LDAF=0.0902;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AF=0.08;ASN_AF=0.08;AMR_AF=0.14;AFR_AF=0.08;EUR_AF=0.07;**

Comment: You just caught me. I was off to bed. Let me see if I can do this first.

Comment: That's ok! Easy :-)  Please see the edit above. I'll be back on line in about 5-6 hrs. Goodluck!

Comment: above code is working but each column should be separated by tab space

Comment: Now there are space between the column..Replace that with tab space

Answer (score 0):

This should work (assuming you have enough disk space to store the expanded .gz files):

```
zcat 1 | awk '{print $1$2,$0}' | sort > new1
zcat 2 | awk '{print $1$2,$0}' | sort > new2
join new1 new2 -11 -21 -o "2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 1.6 1.7"|sed 's/ C:/;REF=/'|sed 's/ G:/;ALT=/' > output
```

Comment: all the 8 columns should be separated by **tab space** can you rearrange the command

Comment: This will replaces the spaces by tabs: `join new1 new2 -11 -21 -o "2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 1.6 1.7"|sed 's/ C:/;REF=/'|sed 's/ G:/;ALT=/'|sed 's/ /\t/g' > output`

Comment: C and G are changing .Here I have given an example ,both files are contains more than 1 million reords.**1st and 2nd column are matching and values before ':' of 5th column of first file and 4th column of 2nd files are equel and 6th column(values before ':') of first and 5th column of second files are equel and output is creating based on this match.Will get the clear idea from input and output line and both files are .gz files**.Just consider the column not values

Comment: I tried this command before **awk 'FNR==NR { split($NF,a,":"); b[$1,$2]=a[2]; next } ($1,$2) in b { print $0 ";ALT=" b[$1,$2] }' <(gzip -dc input1.vcf.gz) <(gzip -dc input2.vcf.gz)  > output.vcf** but little confused how to compare 4 and 5 th column