# How do I generate an output from two input files based on column matches?

Tags: shell, sed, awk

Input1

**1 886817**    2   122 **C**:0.983607  **T**:0.0163934

**1 886817**    3   123 **C**:2.111 **CATTTT**:1.11

input 2

**1 886817**    rs10465241  **C**   **T** 100   PASS AC=1573;

**1 886817**    .   **C**   **CATTTT**  874 PASS AVGPOST=0.9884;

Output

1   886817  rs10465241  C   T   100 PASS AC=1573;REF=0.983607;ALT=0.0163934

1   886817  .   C   CATTTT  874 PASS AVGPOST=0.9884;REF=2.111;ALT=1.11

Output is generated based on bolded column matches.REF and ALT values are adding

Comment: And why do you keep asking the seemingly same question over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

I think I just answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739020/i-need-to-merge-two-files-and-create-a-new-files) question. Some minor changes however:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { split($5,a,":"); split($6,b,":"); c[$1,$2,a[1],b[1]]="REF=" a[2] ";ALT=" b[2]; next } ($1,$2,$4,$5) in c { print $0 c[$1,$2,$4,$5] }' file1 file2
```

Results:

```
1 886817 rs10465241 C T 100 PASS AC=1573;REF=0.983607;ALT=0.0163934
1 886817 . C CATTTT 874 PASS AVGPOST=0.9884;REF=2.111;ALT=1.11
```